# countrycode package is not converting cown to iso3c

Tags: r, country-codes

I installed `countrycode` and called it in Rstudio. Here is my code:

```
countrycode("ccode", "cown", "iso3c" warn = TRUE nomatch = NA)
```

I get an error message saying:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "countrycode("ccode", "cown", "iso3c", warn=TRUE nomatch"
```

where `ccode` is the name of the variable I am trying to convert, `cown` indicates that `ccode` is in the numeric form of the correlates of war code, and `iso3c` is the code I am trying to transform it into.

What am I doing wrong? I think I'm following the example in the countrycode pdf exactly. When I search my dataframe I can't find the `iso3c` variable that I assume should be created. There is no new response variable with another name either.

Comment: missing a comma after `TRUE`

Comment: Thanks :) that helped but shouldn't this produce an iso3c variable in the dataset? I don't see it.

Comment: Also, is it a problem that the observations in my dataset are events (rebel activity) that can occur several times in a single country? That is, its not organized by country, but rather by event. I use the cow code as the sourcevar for my origin, but do I need to be using custom_match? The cran pdf doesn't explain this very much.  Would the custom_match=sourcevar? Thanks, I'ma newbie in R

Answer (score 0):

If `ccode` is a vector containing strings/characters with CoW codes in it, then you should pass `sourcevar = ccode` not `sourcevar = "ccode"`.

```
library(countrycode)
ccode <- c(2, 220, 255, 111)
countrycode(ccode, "cown", "iso3c", warn = TRUE, nomatch = NA)
```

You can pass an individual string/character to `sourcevar` though if you want...

```
countrycode("2", "cown", "iso3c", warn = TRUE, nomatch = NA)
```